# Limiting how much physical memory the kernel can manage with the "mem" environment variable

Tags: linux, memory-management

I've inherited supporting some linux kernel drivers (in which my experience is very limited).  My question is as follows.  It's an embedded environment and the hardware has 512MB of physical memory. However, the boot parameters that are passed to the kernel limits the memory to 256MB by using the variable linuxMem=mem=256M.  In my research of this environment variable, I am of the understanding that
this limits the amount of memory that the kernel can manage to 256MB.
Yet in some application code that runs on my target, I see an open of /dev/mem and a subsequent mmap of the returned file descriptor and the offset parameter of the mmap call is in the upper 256MB of physical memory.
And things seem to be working fine.  So my question is "why does it work if the kernel supposedly does not know about the upper 256MB?"

Comment: How exactly did you map the mmap-returned offset to physical memory?

Comment: There must have been a reason for this choice. Could be that the upper 256MB is not addressable, or does not fit in the tag-registers. (does it have an MMU ?)

Comment: Here is the actual mmap call. mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fdDevMem, (off_t)physMemPtr).  And there is an MMU.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, mem=256M is a kernel parameter, not an environment variable. This parameter only tells the kernel to use so much memory, but it does not make the system completely blind to the physical chip installed in the machine. It can be used to simulate a system with less physical memory than is actually available, but it is not fully equivalent to opening up your box and pulling out one of the memory chips.

Looking at [the docs for this parameter](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt#1578), you can explicitly see that addresses outside of limited range can be used in some situations, that's why they recommend also using `memmap=` in some cases. So, you can't allocate memory for your app above the limit, but you can look at what is found at some physical address, and it seems some device drivers make use of this possibility.

Comment: So I did some more poking around the driver code and discovered that the init function of one of the drivers is doing a request_mem_region of the upper 256MB followed by a ioremap_nocache of the same 256MB.  So it smells like this is how the kernel knows about the upper 256MB.  It appears that the "write" function of that same driver is also doing the copy_from_user calls to actually write into that memory.

Answer (score 2):

`mmap()` returns virtual addresses, not physical ones.

It's perfectly possible for a device to only have 64MB of memory and for `mmap()` to map something around 1GB.

Comment: But the "offset" parameter of the mmap call is into the upper 256MB which I'm guessing the kernel knows nothing about because of the "linuxmem=mem=256MB" environment variable.  Maybe I'm missing your point, Kristof.

Comment: No, you're offset 256MB against **virtual** address 0. The wikipedia article on virtual memory explains better than I can.

Comment: The addresses returned by `mmap()` are virtual, but the mapped file `/dev/mem` is an interface to physical memory, not virtual memory (frames vs pages). So for this file the 'virtual' offset (I find this name a bit misleading, but let's skip this for now) translates one to one to the difference in physical address. kook's issue is not that the returned address is some big value, but that it is legal to read from `/dev/mem` at an offset bigger than the limit set in the kernel (but smaller than physical memory) without causing a segmentation fault. See my answer for an explanation.